# Heroku button failed to configure environment

Tags: heroku

I've tried to create a `app.json` to enable Heroku button.

https://github.com/tkawachi/sslreminder/tree/btn

My `app.json` seems to be valid by [app.json validate](https://github.com/app-json/app.json#validating-a-manifest).
But it failed Configure Environment when I tried to deploy from [this deploy URL](https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/tkawachi/sslreminder/tree/btn).
[image]

How can I fix the failure, or investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the BUILDPACK_URL is causing issues?

```
"BUILDPACK_URL": {
     "description": "Ensure we use an updated go buildpack",
     "value": "https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git"
},
```